# How can I access a Windows PC from a browser?

Tags: remote-desktop

I need a way to remote desktop access my PC at home from a browser. I cannot install any apps, I cannot use ChromeRemoteDesktop, RealVNC, or TeamViewer. Please help me find a way!

Comment: what operating systems are involved?

Comment: https://www.accuwebhosting.com/blog/how-to-connect-remote-desktop-using-a-web-based-interface/

Comment: I want to Remote desktop into a windows PC from a chromebook, but I cannot download anything or get extensions.

Comment: Then I don't think it is possible.

Comment: So I was thinking of coding my own, I know enough Java to code the server, but I'd have to code the client in JS and I don't know any. I'd also have to somehow convert a BufferedImage java class to something usable by JS, and that will not be easy.

Comment: My granpa told me anything worth doing will be hard. maybe if you figure it out you can monetize your hard work.

Comment: There is [Windows Remote Desktop Connection](https://remoteaccess.itarian.com/faq/remote-access/how-can-i-remotely-access-another-computer-for-free/), but it must be enabled before you access your PC... *from the PC*.

Comment: Yeah that is OK I just need to be able to access it from a browser.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Getscreen.me](https://getscreen.me/), it allows you to connect using a normal link. That's exactly what you need.